# UIScrollView inside UITableViewCell With horizontal Paging on IPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

**i am trying to make tableview with custom cell . every cell have uiscrollview inside it and page control .. how can i do that ?? any idea ?**
thx in advance. this video may help [Press Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6PQojyecKM)

Comment: If you would already knew how to implement a custom table cell using a controller that subclasses UITableViewCell, you would place a scrollView in the cell, then use class' properties to populate the srcoll.

Comment: i am trying to do that .. but can you please check the above video and give me hints about the structure of that app .. thx again Teodor

Comment: Dude, there is nothing complicated with that app from the video. Now I understand why are you trying to put scrolls into table cells. but that's a bad approach, tableViews are for tables. In the app, the devs just put different scrollviews within the viewController's view.

Comment: Of course I can give you hints, but it's not about a minor thing, it's about an entire application code design, that it's up to you to start building. It depends of how many pages will you have, how many scrolls will you have per page, what else actions would you need to perform, how to slide from a page to another, bla-bla-bla. All is simple, it's just a matter of some starting code/behavior management

Comment: Meanwhile you might accept jaydee3's answer, as I agree with him.

Comment: ok thx so much :) Teodor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a UIScrollView on your tableViewCell.contentView and enable paging.