# iOS Create iBook like interface inside UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I need to display some content inside a grouped table view. At the same time, a cell inside my table has content that exceeds its bounds. I do not want user to scroll to view the entire content.

As an alternative, I want to make this cell such that it has a paged view - the pages are created on the fly based on content length. I will use its backgroundView property which will lay out as pages.

I found [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH4-SW8) but its design is too complex just for my one cell. Also I could not grasp many parts in it.

I found [this library named Leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves) but I am not sure there are many examples that have used it successfully. I do not know what I would need to modify in it so as to fit it inside my single cell. The example that is given with it successfully shows PDF and Image along pages, but there is no example of plaintext rendering.

Any pointers? Any other sources that can suit my purpose?

Comment: Well I strongly believe iBook is using `UICollectionView`

Comment: Does it use it also for page content?

Comment: @ Nirav, adding page controller for the sake of 1 cell or a few of them is a big overkill to me. Why don't you check the link in my answer for manipulating the cell to change its size according to the text amount.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the cell view that would resize itself according to the text contet. So if some cells have larger text content and some have smaller text it would automatically resize the cell. Here is a two part tutorial that does exactly the trick you are looking for. Hope it helps you out.
http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-resizing-a-uitableviewcell-to-hold-variable-amounts-of-text/

Comment: +1 for good tutorial. However I would plan to use this as last resort as conceptually it should be possible to page along inside any view.

Comment: It is possible by creating a custom cell adding a uiview inside it. The adding scrollview and page controll inside that. There might be other ways to achieve that but that's off the top of my head. As I said, lots of work around. It might not worth the effort. But coding is about exploring new territories. Let me know if you need additional help my friend

Comment: It's been done at many places such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879310/uiscrollview-inside-uitableviewcell-with-horizontal-paging-on-ipad - however approach mentioned there doesn't work for me. I removed textLabel from cell and then added it again as part of scrollview, which I made part of contentview as per your code but it doesn't work. It obscures the text.

Comment: I believe the tut deals with uitextview not a textlabel. Try checking out the part 1 for adding the textview to cell then you can use that to increase the size of the cell as the text get bigger. I the link you mentioned the approach is the same as what I explained in my other comment. Custom cell, scrollview paging enabled. But how many pages? How many scroll views to how many cells? The design of your app becomes very complicated. It's up to you.

Comment: I got around the text obscuring issue with label. It was just some stupid frame thing. But now is the real issue - how to page? I have pagingEnabled=Yes. Yet, it doesn't seem to scroll or go to next page.

Comment: Did you check the IB for enabling paging and scrolling?

Comment: I am adding it at runtime. For which control I need to scrolling enabled?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30991/discussion-between-code-monkey-and-nirav-bhatt)